# Datatables columns search. Selecting columns to replace with input fields

Tags: jquery, datatable

Im using datatables to create table with searchable columns according to this example: 
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Problem is, i need the filters on only some of the columns, which i can select like this ".columns([0,2,4])"

This is the script that changes headers to input fields of **all** the columns:

```
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );
```

Where should i put

```
.columns([0,2,4]
```

for it to convert the headers of only these columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CSS` filters in jquery to keep search for only those columns which are required as below:

```
$('#example tfoot th:nth-child(1),th:nth-child(3),th:nth-child(5)').each( function () {
        var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/rzrocxat/)**